# GitLab Pages Client Side Routing with React Router v6 and ViteJS

Tags: reactjs, deployment, react-router, gitlab-ci, vite

#### Problem

- When I visit the `/` route, and then click links and navigate to pages, everything works alright.
- When I paste the URL of some route in the browser, e.g. `https://<GITLAB_STUFF>/iiser-bhopal/description`, then it goes to the **404 page**, whereas if I go to the same URL by clicking a link in my `/` route, it works.

#### Setup

I have created a React app, with React Router v6 to handle routing. I want to deploy it to GitLab Pages. I have `.gitlab-ci-yml` configured and also set the `basename` prop in `<BrowserRouter>` and `base` in `vite.config.ts` to my repo name (`iiser-bhopal`)

- `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
image: node:16.5.0
pages:
  stage: deploy
  cache:
    key:
      files:
        - package-lock.json
      prefix: npm
    paths:
      - node_modules/
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
    - cp -a dist/. public/
    - cp 404.html public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

- `vite.config.ts`

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: "/iiser-bhopal/",
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

- `<BrowserRouter>` component in `src/main.tsx`

```js
// ... Some code
<BrowserRouter basename="/iiser-bhopal/">
  <App />
</BrowserRouter
// ... Some more code
```

**PS** *Please help. I am on a tight deadline.*

At first routing didn't work even from the `/` route. It started working after I provided the `basename` and set the `base` in `vite.config.ts`.

But after that this problem persists